# How to split curl and npm command from compose entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-entrypoint

I'm using in docker-compose entrypoint two commands:

```
entrypoint: ["curl", "-X", "working command","&&","npm", "working command"]
```

When I'm using them separately they are working, but when I used provided solution it looks curl catch npm command and it can't be executed in a proper way. So how to split them?
Is there any solution without using bash script, like

```
entrypoint: ["./script.sh","&&","npm", "working command"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple commands on docker ENTRYPOINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121031/multiple-commands-on-docker-entrypoint)

Comment: I should add that I can't use a solution with bash, so I stuck in a place...

Comment: Without using bash or without using bash script? Does b0gusb's answer meet your requirement?

Comment: Without bash script, b0gusb answered :)

Comment: If my answer solved the problem, click the big checkbox to accept it ;)

Comment: Yeah! Sorry for this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
 entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "curl -X working_command && npm working_command"]
```

For example print`curl` output and `npm` version:

```
 entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "curl https://stackoverflow.com && npm --version"]
```

In alternative use both entrypoint and command:

```
entrypoint: /bin/sh
command: -c "curl -X working_command && npm working_command"
```

or simply:

```
entrypoint: /bin/sh -c "curl https://stackoverflow.com && npm --version"
```