# How to run multiple ENTRYPOINT script in docker

Tags: docker

I have a bunch of script inside my docker image

```
script01.sh
script02.sh
script03.sh
...
```

I would like to run them (in a particular order) in the ENTRYPOINT statemant:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["script01.sh", "script02.sh", "script03.sh", ...]
```

I've tryed different formulations (adding "bash", "." in the entrypoint commands), but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestion?

This : [Multiple commands on docker ENTRYPOINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121031/multiple-commands-on-docker-entrypoint) did not work in my case so I wrote a new question as the site suggestet me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple commands on docker ENTRYPOINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121031/multiple-commands-on-docker-entrypoint)

Comment: No: I followed that question in some of my (multiple) attempts but none worked.

Comment: have all your scripts called in the order you want in another bash script like the thread you pointed suggests. even if you did that, mention the issues you faced with that approach so we could support better.

Comment: A container runs _one_ process, then exits.  It can be a shell script if you'd like.  Running it with `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT` will make it easier to debug.  The specific formulation you show runs a single command `script01.sh` with extra parameters `script02.sh`, _etc._; any "command" you pass in the `docker run` command will get passed to `script01.sh` as additional arguments.

Comment: I wrote Multiple commands on docker ENTRYPOINT did not work in my case. Why my qustion is still considered a duplicate?